# Display Rows that Have a 0 count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm trying to accumulate a Year to Date total of the number of incident events in a SQL Server shipping system, for display in a graph.

What I have at the moment:

```
SELECT EventType.Name AS [Incident Name], COUNT(Event.ID) AS [Occurrence]
FROM  Event
INNER JOIN
        PortEvent ON Event.PortEventID = PortEvent.ID
INNER JOIN
        EventType ON PortEvent.EventID = Event.ID

WHERE Event.IsIncident = 1 and Event.Date BETWEEN (Start of Year & Now)
GROUP BY Event.Name
```

What this returns;

```
Incident Name       Occurrence

Incident 1              1
Incident 3              4
Incident 4              7
```

What I want:

```
Incident Name       Occurrence

Incident 1              1
Incident 2              0
Incident 3              4
Incident 4              7
Incident 5              0
```

Is there a way to do this simply? I have seen a few examples on SO, but only for adjacent tables.

Thanks

Comment: Dont use INNER JOIN but LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem in you `EventType ON PortEvent.EventID = Event.ID` condition.The query below must solve your issue.

```
SELECT ET.Name AS [Incident Name], COUNT(E.ID) AS [Occurrence]
FROM EventType ET
  LEFT JOIN PortEvent PE
    ON ET.ID = PE.EventID
  LEFT JOIN Event E
    ON PE.EventID = E.ID
      AND E.IsIncident = 1
      AND E.Date BETWEEN ([Start of Year] AND Now)
GROUP BY ET.Name
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to include in result incidents only you can try this:

```
    ON PE.EventID = E.ID
      AND E.Date BETWEEN ([Start of Year] AND Now)
   WHERE E.IsIncident = 1
GROUP BY ET.Name
```

Comment: More Success with this than the others, but now its displaying all of the events, not just incidents, regardless of the IsIncident bit value.

Comment: You can tune the query be moving predicates from last `ON` clause to `WHERE` clause depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, got it working on my own eventually, with your help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Simply using left joins is insufficient. You need to re-order your query so all event types are in the left-most recordset (that's how I visualize it anyway). Additionally, you need to get rid of the where clause and add it to the event table's join because, if not, it might as well be an inner join.

```
SELECT
    EventType.Name AS [Incident Name], COUNT(Event.ID) AS [Occurrence]
FROM  EventType
LEFT JOIN PortEvent ON Event.PortEventID = PortEvent.ID
LEFT JOIN Event ON PortEvent.EventID = Event.ID and Event.IsIncident = 1 and Event.Date BETWEEN (Start of Year & Now)
GROUP BY Event.Name
```

Comment: Same results as above, displaying all events, not just those with IsIncident set to 1

Comment: @Alex you need to provide more information. Set up a SQL Fiddle

Comment: Got it solved Thanks. Through input from you and a bit of trial and error by me. Much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

(CASE WHEN COUNT(Event.ID) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(Event.ID) END) AS [Occurrence]

Answer (score -1):

Change the INNER JOIN of the EventType to a Left Join. This will return the Event and zero or more of the EventType

```
SELECT EventType.Name AS [Incident Name], COUNT(Event.ID) AS [Occurrence] 
FROM  Event
LEFT JOIN
        PortEvent ON Event.PortEventID = PortEvent.ID
LEFT JOIN
        EventType ON PortEvent.EventID = Event.ID

WHERE Event.IsIncident = 1 and Event.Date BETWEEN (Start of Year & Now)
GROUP BY Event.Name
```